# How to define a custom block regions in moodle theme designing?

Tags: php, html, css, moodle

I am trying to design a new theme, that having **side-pre** region and **bottom region**.
In this bottom region(From left to right) I have to add 4 blocks side by side. Please help me, how to define the region(area, location) and in which files I have to modify.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of moodle are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set your custom region in theme/config.php file, for example -

```
'course' => array(
        'file' => 'general_layout.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'bottom-region' ),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-pre',
        'options' => array('langmenu' => true),
    ),
```

And define region in layout file theme/layout/yourlayout.php

```
<div id="region-pre" class="block-region">
   <div class="region-content">
       <?php echo $OUTPUT->blocks_for_region('bottom-region') ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

For more detail look into moodle doc - 
http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes_2.0

Comment: I think it's a good idea to check if the region has indeed content with this line of code: `$PAGE->blocks->region_has_content('my-region-name', $OUTPUT);`, otherwise Moodle could give an error. A working example is here: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes_2.0_creating_your_first_theme

Answer (score -4):

In Theme selector, you can choose theme that u like 
eg.... **Site administration ->  Appearance  ->  Themes  -> Theme selector**